# Accepting logfile as parameter and calling a function if filename is passed but file doesn't exist

Tags: linux, bash, shell-script

I'm currently a bit confused regarding arguments and parameters for a question.

I currently have to accept the log filename as a parameter (For example, `/var/log/secure-<yyyymmdd>`) but default to `/var/log/secure` if no arguments are given.

How do I accept the log filename as a parameter? I think it might be the phrasing of the question, but I don't quite get what it means.

This is a snippet of the current code I have done so far before this question:

```
#!/bin/bash
grep " su: " /var/log/secure | while read -r abc; do   
echo "$abc"
done
```

For the 2nd part, I have to create a function that exits with code 2 (I'm working on that currently) and afterwards, call that function if a filename is passed but the file doesn't exist. Would I do something like this? It feels wrong but not sure where.

```
IF [ -d /var/log/secure ]
then

else
runfunction
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To set a variable to the first command line argument, you would do

```
pathname=$1
```

To set it to a default value in case the argument is not available or if it's empty, use

```
pathname=${1:-/var/log/secure}
```

The general form is `${parameter:-word}`.  This is a [standard POSIX parameter expansion](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_06_02), and it's also documented in the manual of your shell.

The `-d` test tests whether the given string corresponds to an existing directory path (or is a symbolic link to one that exists).  The `-f` test is for regular files in the same way, and `-e` covers anything (will be true if the name exists, regardless of what it is a name of).

To negate the sense of a test, you would use `!`, so you get

```
if [ ! -f "$pathname" ]; then
    myfunction
fi
```

or, using short-circuit syntax,

```
[ ! -f "$pathname" ] && myfunction
```

This would call `myfunction` if the string in the `pathname` variable did not designate an existing regular file (or a link to one).

---

A complete script that takes a command line argument (a path) with a default value and exits with exit status 2 if the given path does not correspond to an existing regular file.

```
#!/bin/bash

pathname=${1:-/var/log/secure}

if [ ! -f "$pathname" ]; then
    printf 'There is no file called "%s"\n' "$pathname"
    exit 2
fi

printf 'The file "%s" exists\n' "$pathname"
```

Comment: Thanks, so following the if statement, would this work 

pathname=${1:-/var/log/secure}

exitcode()

{

        exit 2
  
}

if [ ! -f "$pathname" ]; then

    exitcode
 
fi (Sorry, not sure how to format a comment but this is how it looks https://i.imgur.com/5cHQpJD.png )

Comment: @Zanders2001 Yes, but I so real point in using the function when you can just conditionally call `exit 2` directly.

Comment: I think its just to get a general idea of it, this is our first script that we've worked on in class (And my first bash script). Also regarding the first question, I'm still a bit confused about accepting log filename as a parameter. This is what I have so far https://i.imgur.com/WTx6nPR.png

Comment: @Zanders2001 See updated answer.